# What is definition of Cohen–Eisenstein series?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, eisenstein-series, half-integral-weight

I only find Cohen–Eisenstein series of weight 3/2 (in the paper *[A note on the Fourier coefficients of a Cohen-Eisenstein series](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03971)*). I founded some general definition in "Modular Forms with Integral and Half-Integral Weights by Dingyi Pei and Xueli Wang" section 7.4. But I am not able to relate to the description in the paper.

Comment: As things stand, this does not seem like a suitable question for MO.  Where did you see the definition?  Where did you see a reference, without definition, to the general case?

Comment: I found the definition in the following paper  https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03971

Comment: I found several hits when searching for "Cohen Eisenstein series" in google (eg section 3 of this: http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1274-22.pdf), though it's not clear how the definitions relate to the one in the paper you give.

Comment: I founded some general definition in "Modular Forms with Integral and Half-Integral Weights by Dingyi Pei and Xueli Wang" section 7.4 I am not able to relate to the description in the paper.

Comment: Have you looked at Cohen's paper (Math Ann 1975)?  Even with the edit, I don't really understand what this question is asking.